# Semantically / Pragmatically correct / incorrect sentences

Tags: semantics, pragmatics

I am revising for my NLP quiz and am getting confused at the difference between semantic and pragmatic. I studied that semantic is the study of words and their meaning in sentences while pragmatic takes context into consideration.

I have some examples below of a quiz that I am looking through. It still confuses me and I hope to ask my professor soon but would like some help here so I can ask better questions when I meet him.

Based on [Syntactically correct, semantically incorrect sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29504/syntactically-correct-semantically-incorrect-sentence) and the solutions below, semantically *incorrect* sentences are sentences whose syntax is correct but do not make any sense when bringing in general knowledge. Example: `The green apple ate a juicy bug.` Apples don't eat things.

1) But what about pragmatically incorrect sentences ? How do I identify one ? The solutions below did not state the reason sentence no. 6 is pragmatically correct.

2) Can a sentence be semantically incorrect but pragmatically correct ?

[image]

Comment: Whatever your (unattributed) source, I think it's garbage. I don't recognise any value in the classifications "lexical" and "pragmatic" in this context.  But presumably what the (misguided, imho) author has in mind is that *some* utterances are syntactically valid but clearly ***not true*** (such as *An inch is longer than a metre*), as opposed to utterances that simply don't make (pragmatic/practical) sense - such Chomsky's *Colorless green ideas sleep furiously*, which is generally described as "syntactically valid, but semantically nonsense", not "non-pragmatic".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Its an NLP course from my university http://coling.epfl.ch/quizzNote01-2017-corr.pdf Would u say that a semantically correct sentence is one that agrees with general knowledge whereas a pragmatically correct sentence is non-ambiguous in its interpretation ?

Comment: any ideas anyone

Comment: any ideas anyone

Comment: everyone here only knows basic english ?

Comment: I assume the the *red* text in your example is actually from the "teacher". But it contains so many errors and shortcomings that I really wouldn't bother with it at all as a source of useful information about English.

Comment: Kong, I suspect I'm not the only one thinking if that posting formed any part of any course, you should be demanding a refund and looking for a hugely better college.